# python .exe в автозапуск

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

Можно ли `pyinstaller`-ом превратить файл `.py` в `.exe`, а затем в автозапуск или через планировщик?

Comment: Вам обязательно exe? А что если bat, который будет висеть в автозапуске и в планировщике?

Comment: Да и bat - лишнее. Можно прямо так, со всеми аргументами.

Comment: можно, но зачем такие сложности ?

Comment: Программа exe с помощью кода сама себя добавляла в автозагрузки (На python)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно проверять наличие только что запущенного скрипта в папке автозагрузки, и если его там нет - копировать туда.

```
import os, sys

Thisfile = sys.argv[0] # Полный путь к файлу, включая название и расширение
Thisfile_name = os.path.basename(Thisfile) # Название файла без пути
user_path = os.path.expanduser('~') # Путь к папке пользователя

if not os.path.exists(f"{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\{Thisfile_name}"):
        os.system(f'copy "{Thisfile}" "{user_path}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup"')
        print(f'{Thisfile_name} добавлен в автозагрузку')
```

Но это будет работать только в случае, если у вас скрипт скомпилирован в .exe
В противном случае, вам помимо самого скрипта, в папке автозагрузки нужно будет создать **.bat** или **.cmd** файл, который уже будет запускать скрипт в интерпретаторе.

```
@echo off
python PythonCode.py
exit
```